# Highcharts - Show x-Axis labels in legends

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have implemented Stacked Column chart using highcharts. where x-axis is showing the Manufacturer name and y-axis showing respective models in the form of stacks.

[Stacked column chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekOZK.png)

Now the legends shows model names here. But I want x-axis labels. i.e. Manufacturer names.

Here is the example jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked

```js
// Data retrieved from:
// - https://en.as.com/soccer/which-teams-have-won-the-premier-league-the-most-times-n/
// - https://www.statista.com/statistics/383679/fa-cup-wins-by-team/
// - https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/history/winners/
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Major trophies for some English teams',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Arsenal', 'Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester United']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Count trophies'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 70,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'BPL',
        data: [3, 5, 1, 13]
    }, {
        name: 'FA Cup',
        data: [14, 8, 8, 12]
    }, {
        name: 'CL',
        data: [0, 2, 6, 3]
    }]
});
```

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCrPQ.png)
As you can see, it is showing BPL, FA Cup and CL is legends. But I want Arsenal, Chelsea, LiverPool and Manchester United

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please provide us what you tried to do with code sample, or stackblitz

Comment: @Q.Rey Here is the example jsFiddle  
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked

As you can see, it is showing BPL, FA Cup and CL is legends. But I want Arsenal, Chelsea, LiverPool and Manchester United

Comment: This doesn't make sense, the legend explains the color-coded information from the  bars (trophies); what colors will you assign to  each team? If you really want to repeat the axes categories (teams) somewhere inside the plot, you can do that with an [annotation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module#the-concept), not a legend. Also, in the manufacturer/car model case, since each manufacturer has its (different) set of models, I'm not sure that this is the appropriate type of chart at all

Answer (score 0):

In order to show as the legend similar to x-axis labels , you need to parse your data (or create a whole series in your backend) to format like this:

```
series: [{
    name: "First",
    data: [3]
  }, {
    name: "Second",
    data: [4]
  }, {
    name: "Third",
    data: [2]
  }]
```

As soon as you create a separate series, they will show up in the legend.
jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6f9xcz7j

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you will need to parse your data as follows:

```
   series: [{
        data: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
          name: 'BPL',
          color: 'red'
        }, {
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
          name: 'FA Cup',
          color: 'green'
        }, {
          x: 0,
          y: 3,
          name: 'CL',
          color: 'blue'
        }],
        name: 'Arsenal'
      }],
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uh4nky72/